# Close Tab Based on Title

Tags: perl, firefox, mechanize, www-mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

How would I close a tab based on it's title using `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`?

Here is what I currently have:

```
my $ff = Firefox::Application->new();
my @tab_info = $ff->openTabs();
foreach my $tab (@tab_info) {
    if($tab->{title} eq "TITLE HERE") {
        $ff->closeTab($tab->{location});
    }
}
```

The documentation for [closeTab()](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/Firefox/Application.pm#$ff-%3EcloseTab(_$tab_[,$repl]_)) just says 'Close the Given Tab' with no information on what the given tab is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `$ff->closeTab($tab->{tab})`.  See the [Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/Cookbook.pod), for example.  A complete program:

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;    
my $ff = Firefox::Application->new();

my $title_to_close = "Title of the page to close ...";

# This will pull in all currently opened tabs   
my @tabs = $ff->openTabs();

foreach my $tab (@tabs) {
    if ($tab->{title} =~ /$title_to_close/) {
        print "Close tab: $tab->{title}";
        $ff->closeTab($tab->{tab});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More concisely:

```
$ff->closeTab($_->{tab}) for grep { $_->{title} eq 'TITLE HERE' } $ff->openTabs;
```